# Shopping cart items not showing in customer view

Tags: php, cart, magento, magento-1.7

Running Magento 1.7.2.

When inside the customer view in the administrator it shows 1 item in the customers cart but not the details. I’ve attached a screen shot. Does anyone know what the issue could be or can you verify that it’s working properly so I know it’s my installation?

Thanks.

**[View Screenshot Here](http://www.whitesharkcreations.com/magento_bug.jpg)**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Solved]

on app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\CustomerController.php

1.7.0

```
public function viewCartAction()
{
$this->_initCustomer();
$layout = $this->loadLayout()
->getLayout()
->getBlock('admin.customer.view.cart')
->setWebsiteId();
$this->renderLayout();
}
```

change to :

```
public function viewCartAction()
{
$this->_initCustomer();
$layout = $this->loadLayout()
->getLayout()
->getBlock('admin.customer.view.cart')
->setWebsiteId($this->getRequest()->getParam('website_id'))
->toHtml();
$this->renderLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in 1.7.0.2.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=14101