# In magento admin under customer's account the items added to cart are not visible

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am working in my localhost.I have a registered user.

When the registered user adds the product to the cart in frontend.

But when I go to admin **customers >manage customers** and check there customer view it does not show any product in customer's cart.

How can I fix this?!
[image]

Is this a bug in magento

Comment: It has been resolved at another [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13062866)